using std::mutex without including it
I am trying to build openrave on the production branch and I can't understand what I am seeing. The code looks like it isn't including #include <mutex> but it is making use of std::mutex everywhere. I am sure I am missing something. How is that possible? How can the code make use of std::mutex without including it directly?
One example is the file sensorsystem.h (include/openrave/sensorsystem.h) at https://github.com/rdiankov/openrave/tree/production/include/openrave.
Any help would be appreciated.

You can also raise an issue on openrave repository and ask them.

Including any standard library header (generally) may or may not cause the declarations of any other standard library header to be included as well. It is unspecified and will vary between implementations. So one can get lucky (or unlucky?) forgetting to include a header that one should have included and it still working. It may work on ones own compiler but then not on another. It should be fixed if it is really missing the <mutex> include.

Maybe thread header includes it implicitly. In any case the code is bad and is not guaranteed to always compile.

All their files have #include <openrave/openrave.h> that has #include <openrave/environment.h>, this file contains
#include <mutex>


I think that is probably the right answer. This seems extremely sketchy as the preprocessor condition in that file doesn't always include  before making use of it. Also, I thought you should always include what you use before using it. Moreover, I didn't know you could use something like a std::mutex declaration in a header file if its corresponding cpp file includes the appropriate header for mutex. Anyone please correct me but that seems like a bad practice, and can lead to compilation issues.

@Pinknoise Header inclusion is just simple text replacement of the header file into the .cpp file. What is relevant is whether or not the declaration appears before the first use after doing this text replacement (recursively). If there is a use before the first declaration, the program is going to be ill-formed. The C++ language doesn't actually have any concept of a difference between .h and .cpp files.

@Pinknoise Because you never know what library headers include what other library headers as an implementation detail, you can never rely on code not compiling if you forget to include the appropriate headers or include them not early enough. For the standard library this is explicitly unspecified (for the most part) and for third-party libraries there are also rarely any guarantees that one header doesn't include another one. Therefore, each time you a new library functionality is used, one should check whether an additionally include is formally required, even if it compile without one.

Thanks all for your comments. That all makes sense now.
